# Why Y doesn't work like `yy`, but works like `y$`?

Tags: neovim, cut-copy-paste, normal-mode

Why `Y` command doesn't work like `yy`, but works like `y$`? I mean, everyone says that it does work like `yy`, but for me, it doesn't. So how do I fix it?

For the close reason: [This question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6061/why-is-y-a-synonym-for-yy-instead-of-y) doesn't help me. I'm asking the opposite question, about why for me, `Y` works like `y$` on my machine instead of `yy`, and not why `Y` works like `yy` instead of `y$`.

Comment: @Mass No, it's the opposite of this question, Everyone seems to say that `Y` works like `yy` instead of `y$` and I have no clue why.

Comment: hmm perhaps you're using neovim?   https://neovim.io/doc/user/change.html#Y-default

Comment: @Mass Yes... I'm using Neovim.

Comment: The Neovim team has made the choice to follow the doc suggestion and provides a default mapping of `Y` to `y$`. More information with `:help Y` or `:help default-mappings`.

Comment: Well then, I added the neovim tag and voted to reopen. Vivian's comment above should already be the answer you're looking for. On a side note, `:help Y` explains what's going on for *both* Vim and NeoVim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to finally collect all our misunderstandings about the question: the OP is using neovim which [makes `Y` act more like `C`/`D` by default](https://neovim.io/doc/user/change.html#Y-default). This is apparently still documented at `:help Y`, and could be switched (if desired) by a similar mapping as that of many Vim users:

```
nnoremap Y yy
```

(I can't think why you would need bare `map` here, but I'll correct it if someone can point out what I'm missing.)

Comment: Bare `:map` is what Bram wrote into `:help Y` almost 20 years ago. I quoted it but I don't think it's needed. I also like how this "fix" restores inconsistent behavior from the 1970's. To each their own.

Comment: @Friedrich, yes, I recognized the quote :) I suggest it be updated, though.

Answer (score 3):

As [D. Ben Knoble](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/10604/d-ben-knoble) already said in his comment, `:help Y` says:

> If you like "Y" to work from the
> cursor to the end of line (which is more logical,
> but not Vi-compatible) use ":map Y y$".

From this, we can infer two things:

- it was a well-known incompatibility that compelled somebody to explain it, including a workaround.
- it wasn't important enough to be added to `cpoptions`.

Coming back to your question, for Vim the answer is "Vi-compatibility" and you can add the mapping above to your `vimrc`.

For the original Vi, I don't know the answer.

Based on gut feeling, I would say I'd use `yy` more frequently than `y$` so that may have been the reason for giving it a one-letter command. This, however, is just my theory.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW…

In Vi, `Y` is "yank current line", while `C` and `D` are "change to end of line" and "delete to end of line", so we have had that mess for a long time.

I don't think I've read a definitive explanation of that discrepancy anywhere but I find the hypothesis that `Y` (really `Shift+y`) was more practical than `y_` (really `y` then `Shift+-`) for a very common action unconvincing. Yes, that's fewer keypresses but `C` and `D` don't work like `Y` despite "change current line" (`c_`) and "delete current line" (`d_`) certainly being as common as "yank current line" and certainly more common than "change to end of line" and "delete to end of line".

It is just some arbitrary mess that has been passed on from generation to generation for decades.

Being a Vim clone at its heart, Vim kept the original incoherent meaning of `Y`, `C`, and `D` but the author was aware that it was silly so you get the little mapping suggestion under `:help Y`.

Note that `Y` was *really* cheaper than `y_` in Vi so it made **kind of** sense in the original context. But Vim has `yy` (and `cc` and `dd`), which is a lot efficient than both `Y` and `y_`, so the suggested mapping brings some much needed consistency without hurting anyone:

- use `Y`, `C`, and `D` to operate "to end of line" (less efficient, for a less common action),
- use `yy`, `cc`, and `dd` to operate on "current line" (more efficient, for a more common action).

Comment: "Arbitrary mess" sounds just as convincing as my own pet hypothesis. It's also a good short description for virtually every software project I ever worked on.